# OVERLAPS function in Impala

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark, impala, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use and overlaps function as in ORACLE or Netezza that takes two date ranges and check if they overlap each other.
Soemthing like this: 
`SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2011-01-28 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01  23:59:59') OVERLAPS (TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 23:59:59');`

What is the best way to do this in Impala or SparkSQL? Unfortunately OVERLAPS does not exist in Impala or SparSQL.
The only thing I can think of is UDF but looking for a work around.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think writing out the logic expressly is clearer than using `OVERLAPS`.  Are the end points included, for instance?

The logic is:

```
select (case when TIMESTAMP '2011-01-28 00:00:00' < TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 23:59:59' AND
                  TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01 00:00:00' < TIMESTAMP '2011-02-01  23:59:59'
             then 1 else 0
        end) as overlaps
```

The logic is.  If you have two ranges, range1 and range2 with start and end times, then they overlap when the first starts before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts:

```
select (case when range1_start < range2_end and range1_end > range2_start
             then 1 else 0
        end) as overlaps
```